# extract xsd used in biztalk application

Tags: biztalk

We can use Biztalk export function to export the binding of an application. However, we do not know how to export the xsd used in the application sendports.

Is it possible to perform this task?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want an XSD for the [Binding Files](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_blogs/b/biztalksyn/archive/2007/07/10/grab-the-biztalk-binding-file-schema-on-the-run.aspx)? XSD's for all artifacts, including schemas published or consumed will be in your application are viewable in [Admin Console for your application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559169.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But I want to export those XSD used in the Binding. IS there any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the actual XSD within the BizTalk Administration Console.
Double click the schema within the Application/Schemas node and you will get the properties of the schema. Selecting Schema on the left side will show you the actual XSD.

Even more handy is the BizTalk documenter tool. This is a third party, open-source tool that is quite well known within the community. It will document anything of your choice within BizTalk, ranging from schemas, mappings to orchestrations and artifacts.

For BizTalk 2006/2009: http://biztalkdocumenter.codeplex.com/

For BizTalk 2010: http://biztalk2010autodc.codeplex.com/

Hope this helps.